# Pivot table twice?

Tags: sql

This is what I'm currently displaying

```
       month           |   Breed|   Hugo | Marco |
       january 2017    |   Lab  |  4    |   5   |
       february 2017   |   Pug  |  7    |   3   |
```

Is it possible to get the table to display breed in a row instead after 
already pivoting the table?

```
    month           |   Hugo | Marco |
    january 2017    |   4    |  5    |
    Breed           |   Lab  |  Pug  |

  SET @query ='SELECT * FROM(SELECT
      petstoreemployee.employeefirstname as employeefirstname
      ,sum(petID.breed) as breeds
      ,Format(date, ''MMMM-yyyy'') as Month
      ,breed as breed
  FROM
      petID, petstoreemployee
  WHERE
      petID.petstoreemployeeID=petstoreemployee.petstoreemployeeID and
      petID.ProjectedPrjID=1
      and
      (petID.date >= ''2017-01-01 00:00:00:000'' AND petID.date <= 
 ''2017-12-31 00:00:00:000'')
  group by petstoreemployee.employeefirstname, Format(date,''yyyy''), breeds

)
as d
PIVOT(
   avg(breeds)
   for employeefirstname
   IN (' + @pet + ')
) as p'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Thanks

Comment: Your desired output makes no sense - "Breed" is not a "month" and there's no obvious relationship between "Hugo" and "Lab". Are you intending to show all breeds in a separate table?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you store your result sets into a #temp table and then do a Select on those results based on how you want it displayed. The end result you want is confusing because your first Column says Month but you have "Breed" in there. Sounds to me that you want to show that Hugo and Marco had 4 Lab and 5 pugs for the month of January.

If that is the case the end result should be like this:

```
       Lab | Pug | Month
Hugo   4   |  0  | January 2017
Marco  0   |  5  | January 2017
```

Also you are using SUM(petid.breed) but in your example it's a VARCHAR not a number.

You will have to play around with this but I hope this helps you get the main idea.

```
  SELECT
        petstoreemployee.employeefirstname as employeefirstname
       ,sum(petID.breed) as breeds
       ,Format(date, ''MMMM-yyyy'') as Month
       ,breed as breed
  INTO #PETTEMP
  FROM PETID A
  JOIN petstoreemployee b on  
       petID.petstoreemployeeID=petstoreemployee.petstoreemployeeID and
       petID.ProjectedPrjID=1 and (a.petID.date >= ''2017-01-01 
       00:00:00:000'' AND b.petID.date <= 
        '2017-12-31 00:00:00:000'')

  group by petstoreemployee.employeefirstname, Format(date,''yyyy''), 
  breeds

  --Do your select here from #pettemp
  -- your first select is your first column
  Select Month,petid from #pettemp
  -- join here for your second column
  join (select * from #pettemp)
  -- join here for your 3rd column
  join (select * from #pettemp)
```